# Angular $http result sort and bind to view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to render results from data pulled from a successful $http.get, push it through two or three functions that sort/concat/filter the data a few different ways, and store for the rest of the apps duration.

I have the following service:

```
myApp.service('versionService', function($http, $log, $q) {

    var self = this;

    this.issues = {
        all: []
    };

    this.versions = {
        all: [],
        byName: [],
        byID: []
    };


    var query = {};
    query.jql = "fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() ORDER BY fixVersion ASC";

    $http({
        url: '/search/versions',
        method: 'POST',
        //cache: true,
        data: query
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            //console.log(response.data.issues);
            for(var i = 0; i < response.data.issues.length; i++) {
                self.issues.all.push(response.data.issues[i]);
                for(var j = 0; j < response.data.issues[i].fields.fixVersions.length; j++) {
                    self.versions.all.push(response.data.issues[i].fields.fixVersions[j]);
                }
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

});
```

My Controller:

```
 myApp.controller('filteredController', function($scope, $http, $log, versionService) {

    $scope.isActive = function(version) {
        return version == versionService.selectedV;
    };

    $scope.issues = {
        all: versionService.issues.all
    };

    $scope.versions = {
        all: versionService.versions.all,
        byName: versionService.versions.byName,
        byID: versionService.versions.byID
    };

});
```

No matter how I try to do it, if I put a sort/filter/concat on this.versions.byName in the controller, it just gives a blank array as a return. I'm guessing because the sort/filter/concat is running before the http.get and loops finish? Obviously this means the view doesn't show anything if I try to pull from vesions.byname/ID/

How do I run functions to sort/filter/concat the data, put it in the other arrays in the versions object, then have that binded to the view?

I was trying to use the following function:

```
var versionsByName = function() {

    var prev = null;

    self.versions.byName = self.versions.all
        .concat()
        .sort()
        .filter(function (i) {
            if (i.name !== prev.name) {
                prev = i;
                return true;
            }
        })

};
```

No matter where I put it, or if I make it an IIFE, it won't work.

Comment: I don't see where you're populating `this.versions.byName` in your `versionService`, so why would it ever be anything other than an empty array?

Comment: In the code snippet, I am not. no matter where I put versionsByName(), it won't populate the array. I've tried putting it in the '.then' of http and it doesn't work. I believe the loop is still filling the arrays that versiosByName() depends on.

Comment: Is `versionsByName` defined in your `versionService`, where do you invoke the function `versionsByName()`?

Comment: Yes, in my versionService. I've tried multiple ways. I've tried invoking versionsByName in the .then return of my $http, after both loops are done. That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please add this to your code post or create a plunker so we can see exactly where and when the functions get called.

Comment: Although it looks like you're reassigning `self.versions.byName` to a new array while your controller is pointing to the original array so it won't be updated. So you should try `$scope.versions = versionService.versions` in your controller

Comment: Working on a plunker. Hard to do when it all relies on an http.post. and $scope.versions = versionService.versions just returns an object with an array of all, no array of byname/ID.

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.versions = versionService.versions;` in your controller?

Comment: Yes, explained in the post above yours.